# How to make the width of a Text equal to the width of another implicitly measured Text?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

There is a reader app with two Texts, one for the total number of pages and one for the current page. I want the width of the current page Text to be equal to the width of the total page Text, but the width of the total page Text is measured implicitly.

Currently, I can only specify the width like this：

```kotlin
Row {
    Text(modifier = Modifier.width(32.dp), text = "1000") // total page
    Slider(...)
    Text(modifier = Modifier.width(32.dp), text = "1") // current page
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get render text layout, you can use `onTextLayout`. It has all information you may need, including size.

Then you can pass this size to second `Text` modifier:

```kotlin
var totalPageTextWidth by remember { mutableStateOf<Int?>(null) }
val widthModifier = totalPageTextWidth?.let { width ->
    with(LocalDensity.current) { 
        Modifier.width(width.toDp()) 
    }
} ?: Modifier
Text(
    text = "1000",
    onTextLayout = { totalPageTextWidth = it.size.width }
)
Text(
    text = "1",
    modifier = widthModifier
)
```

Answer (score 2):

While Phil's answer may work, I don't believe it to be the correct way to do this. If you want one item to match the width of another item, you are better off using something that allows you to customize the layout/measurement process rather than relying on modifying state via `onTextLayout` and triggering recomposition because of it.

One such way is using `SubcomposeLayout`, which differs from Phil's answer in that it doesn't rely on recomposition to adjust the width of the other text field and instead allows you to get the measurements before the layout phase and use those measurements to determine how something else is going to be measured.

```kotlin
SubcomposeLayout { constraints ->
    val pageTotalPlaceable = subcompose("totalCount") {
        Text(text = "1000")
    }.first().measure(constraints.copy(maxWidth = Constraints.Infinity))
    val currentPagePlaceable = subcompose("currentPage") {
        Text(text = "1")
    }.first().measure(constraints.copy(minWidth = pageTotalPlaceable.width, maxWidth = Constraints.Infinity))


    layout(width = pageTotalPlaceable.width + currentPagePlaceable.width, height = maxOf(pageTotalPlaceable.height, currentPagePlaceable.height)) {
        currentPagePlaceable.placeRelative(0,0)
        pageTotalPlaceable.placeRelative(currentPagePlaceable.width, 0)
    }
}
```